# PDF not readable when copied from MacBook to USB (2.0)

Tags: usb, pdf

I have a perfectly well PDF file on my Mac. I copy it to my 1TB USB, and it suddenly is not readable from USB; only from Mac. I can copy some other movies from Mac to USB and it reads ok from USB afterwards.

Why does this happen to PDF?

Comment: We need some more details.  Does this happen to *all* PDF's or just one particular one?  What are you using to open said PDF, Preview or something else?  What version of macOS are you running?  Have you tried any different software like [Acrobat Reader](https://get.adobe.com/reader/)?

Comment: In addition to Allan's questions, what sort of PDF is it? Is it: (1) one you created, (2) a readily downloadable one, (3) one you _purchased_ in some way, or (4) something else?